# Why am I getting vite:command not found error?

Tags: vite

I have installed vite in my vue.js app. I start the app by typing npm run dev in the main project directory. In the package.json this is defined as:

```
"dev": "vite"
```

but if I try do run this command (or eg. vite build) 'manually' from main directory, I get an error:

```
bash: vite: command not found
```

I also figured out that when I set a new script:

```
"build": "vite build"
```

I can run this command also, although, again, running it manually will result in error as above.

This seems quite illogical to me. Can anybody explain how is it possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you didn't install vite globally (using `npm install -g`), then the vite command will be in `node_modules/.bin` in your main directory. The `npm run` command temporarily [adds that folder](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-run-script#description) to your PATH so it can execute that command. Try running `./node_modules/.bin/vite` to run it without npm.